# How do I convert a C# lambda expression into a delegate?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, delegates

I'm not very familiar lambda and delegate expressions, but I need to work with  .NET 2 framework so I will have to go with delegate.

Let's say I have an example of a

```
process = new Process();
```

and I want to pass additional parameters to the event by customizing it :

```
public void TestHandler(object s, DataReceivedEventArgs e, string mystring)
{
     Console.writeLine(e.Data + "," + mystring);
}
...

process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) => TestHandler(sender, e, "hello"));
```

How should I do this by using a delegate?

I tried to do this:

```
public delegate void TestDelegate(object s, DataReceivedEventArgs e, string mystring);

..eg inside main

TestDelegate testDel = delegate(object s,DataReceivedEventArgs e, string mystring) { TestHandler (s, e, mystring); }; 

process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(testDel);
```

but I guess I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can simply convert the lambda expression to a delegate (anonymous method expression), without creating a new delegate type.

Change this:

```
(sender, e) => TestHandler(sender, e, "hello")
```

Into

```
delegate (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) {
    TestHandler(sender, e, "hello");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot of context I can go of, but the signature for [DataReceivedEventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.datareceivedeventhandler?view=net-5.0) is `public delegate void DataReceivedEventHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e);`. It has two arguments and you're trying to pass a delegate with three arguments in there: `(object s,DataReceivedEventArgs e, string mystring)`.

My guess is you'd have to remove the third argument, `string mystring`.